# Best text color for any background image?

Tags: css

My page backgroud is an image that fills whole page and the changes every time the page is loaded.
I am looking to find a text color and shadow css that will suit every image out there.

My current CSS is text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 1px 1px 0px; color:#222;
It doesnt look too good. Is it possible to change text color automatically based on what type of image it is . Or simply is there a text color and shadow that will suit most images?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Ovf.png

Comment: Take a foreign not synchronized movie and just look at the color of the subtitles and the text border. You cannot go wrong. It's been tested for decades :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graphic design.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

white with a black outline is readable on anything.  If your images are *very* different, I'd go with that.  Or add per-image CSS.

Examples of how to get the effect: http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/